# Converting 'ssh -R' to 'ssh -w'

Tags: ssh, ip, port-forwarding

I use ssh remote port forwarding like this:

```
ssh -R $PUBLIC_IP:80:127.0.0.1:80
```

The local server on 127.0.0.1:80 sees connections as coming from 127.0.0.1. Is there any way at all, hacky or not, to make the ssh client give the original IP address (that connected to $PUBLIC_IP:80) to the local server?

I could run the local server on 192.168.1.x instead of 127.0.0.1 if it makes a difference.

**Edit:** Converting this to a 'ssh -w' tun VPN would be something I'm looking for if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a way to do this.  If you really require this then you need is a VPN. SSH port forwarding basically is just a TCP proxy. If the original source address was used, then the reply wouldn't get back to the SSH server so it could return it to the connected client.

Comment: A 'ssh -w' tun VPN would be great, maybe there is a simple way to set this up for my use case above? I've amended the question.